# How can we tailor a large language model for educational purposes by incorporating instructional and pedagogical-specific skills and knowledge?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

There are domain-specific large language models such as [BioGPT](https://github.com/microsoft/BioGPT#pre-trained-models) that are fine-tuned for biology-related tasks, but they are targeted towards researchers and workers in that field.

If we want to develop a language model for educational use by teachers and students, what pedagogical skills and procedural knowledge should be embedded into it? What tasks should be designed to train the model to effectively utilize those skills?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm confused by the question - are you teaching CS students?  Or is this general education?  And what is the age range of the students?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to train the LLM, and you're asking what should be in it?

Comment: Yes. To embed the knowledge into a LLM. @BenI.